# No guidance as to the preferred topics for people asking questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

After seeing Yet Another "how do I configure ssh?" question on Stack Overflow I thought to myself, "how do these people miss the fact that this site is not for this sort of question?".

Then I realized that there is no guidance as to the preferred topics for Stack Overflow on either the main page or on the [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page. If someone happens to visit the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), they see:

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

...but that's not a very strong statement, and besides, people will only see it if they go looking for it.  Is there any chance we could add some of the text from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as a preamble to the question form?  Maybe just the first paragraph:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask
>   your question!

It seems that might help reduce the amount of dreck that crops up and gets closed because it's been posted in the wrong place.

Comment: I don't have a low rep account to look at this, but I thought there was a lot of guidance for low-rep users when asking questions (and by low rep, I mean <10)

Comment: I don't have a low rep account, either...I guess I can go create one and see what it looks like. I'll do that then.

Comment: I had one, but it has 15 rep now so I can't see what it looks like before the initial "new user" restrictions are remvoed..

Comment: On Stack Overflow (and maybe some other sites?) new users also have to accept the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), which includes: *Our community is defined by [a specific set of topics in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); please stick to those topics and [avoid asking for opinions or open-ended discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).*

Answer (score 10):

I agree. I'm kind of surprised that no one noticed this before, given how the large number of off-topic questions. I only knew to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic because me is smart. No really, I can prove it! One plus two equals... uh... uhhh *gets calculator* lets see... *presses wrong button* Four! AHAAHAHAHAHAAHHHAHAHA See?! Haha! I told you I was smart! Muahahahaha— *dies from sheer stupidity*.

I think that a few excerpts from the Help Center should be shown prominently on the Ask Question page, at least up until a user has somewhere around 50–500 reputation and has asked a question that is not closed and has a positive score. It could look somewhat like this:

> [image]

Comment: I thought something like this existed for very new users (<10 rep), but I could be mistaken.  And if it doesn't then it should exist.

Comment: @psubsee2003: we already have [this Wall Of Text™](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) in place, though I'm not aware of anything else.

Comment: Your screenshot is missing something. In the title input box there's a text: *What's your **programming** question? Be specific.* That doesn't prevent people from asking about candies, credit card, car engines... :/